# file required for ffmpeg portability

Tags: ffmpeg, portability

I'm making a python GUI app and using ffmpeg to encode files. I'm bundling ffmpeg with it, so I'm wondering what do I need to make it portable. Would it work with just the ffmpeg binary in my /opt/local/bin folder?

Answer (score 0):

Whatever binaries you distribute with your application need to be compiled for each target platform you want them to run on.

Comment: What I mean is does the ffmpeg binary for OS X have any dependencies. I understand that I would have to compile it for windows seperately.

Comment: I'm not sure about the one that ships with OS X, but if you build it yourself I think there are three binaries you have to have.  Also, since it is licensed under GPL (or LGPL) you may not be able to redist the version that comes with OS X since LGPL requires certain things of you, and FFmpeg likes to enforce them.  You should read the license very carefully and consult and attorney before you distribute FFmpeg.